# How to avoid inline CSS in React

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Is there a way around not using inline CSS in React when you have something as follows:

```
const stylesObj = { width: 10, height: 20 };
<div className="point-class"
  style={{
     width: stylesObj.width + "px",
     height: stylesObj.height + "px",
  }}
></div>
```

Comment: Classes, styled components, ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Style Components](https://styled-components.com/) was a solution.

Answer (score 0):

you can always change your global.css file

```
.point-class {
 width: 10px,
 height: 10px
}
```

or use this method to add css modules https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-a-css-modules-stylesheet/

Comment: Say the stylesObj has multiple styles and I am creating a list with different styles, would this work?

Comment: what do you mean by multiple styles?

Comment: I would also recommend checking tailwindcss

Answer (score 0):

You can use a more stable approach by defining the style object outside of the component render function.
By defining the styles object outside the component, it remains the same between renders, ensuring that the style prop won't trigger unnecessary re-renders.